# How to use size class to make app compatible to iphone 5, iphone 6, iphone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I am using size class for making my app compatible for iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.
I am using compact width Regular height for this :

[image: Portrait mode]

Is this the correct way for using the xib or storyboard and making the other things leave on iOS ?
Or, do i need to have some other things needed to be added ?

It is showing perfectly in all devices without using Auto-layout.

Do I need to do some more changes ?
Do i need to add 3X images in my resource folder ?

What is the best way to do the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Size classes

Looking up [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html), we can summarize

- **Portrait**: iPhone4s, iPhone5, iPhone6, iPhone6 Plus all use Horizontal **Compact**, Vertical **Regular**.
- **Landscape**: iPhone4s, iPhone5, iPhone6, all use Horizontal **Compact**, Vertical **Compact**.

  **But** iPhone6 Plus uses Horizontal **Regular**, Vertical **Compact**
- **iPad** uses Horizontal **Regular**, Vertical **Regular** for both **Landscape** and **Portrait**

---

### Image resolutions

According to this [Official link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html), 3x image is needed for iPhone6 Plus. You can see the whole specs:

[image: The whole specs]

---

### Best practice

Looks like your app only supports iPhone **Portrait** mode, in this case, your employment of Horizontal **Compact**, Vertical **Regular** is fine.

However, the best way to do it is to design your app with Horizontal **Any**, Vertical **Any**. If you have special case for some devices, for instance, iPad, which uses Regular for both Portrait and Landscape, you can adjust the views, layout constraints for it. The following two pictures show how the same view can have different layouts for different size classes.

- View with **Any Any** size classes

[image: The same view with Any Any size classes]

- The same view with **Regular Regular** size classes

[image: The same view with Regular Regular size classes]

---

### Tricks

You can preview what you have done in storyboard using **preview** feature in xcode, the following steps show you how to do it:

1. Layout all your views in storyboard with different size classes
2. Click [image: Assistance button] on the top right corner
3. In the newly open window, click **Preview** here

[image: Click Preview]

4. Click on the **+** button and select different device for previews.

[image: Example on Preview]

---

### Practice yourself

You can download a sample project [here](https://github.com/ethan-fang/ShowSizeClass). The credit goes to Stanford CS193 course. The video which explains auto layout is [View Controller Lifecycle, Autolayout](http://a737.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/CobaltPublic5/v4/94/04/2f/94042f0b-fba1-730f-e4d4-775a4f611ad6/314-8794522316211007309-08_CS193_2_02_15_WIP01_720p1500cc.mp4) and you can start from **31:30** to **36:30**. But I highly recommend you to check the whole video to get the overall picture.